# How to automatically mount Android device sd card in Linux mint

Tags: debian, linux-mint, mount, android, sd-card

Debian 8 iso hybrid is mounting android device (lenovo k3note) sd card automatically. But Linux mint 17.2 doesn't do so. How to mount Android device sd card automatically in Linux mint?